# RewriteRule for URLs that do not end with dot html/php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect all:

```
<a href="filename"></a>
```

to

```
<a href="get.php?filename"></a>
```

I have started to

```
RewriteRule  !\.(html|php)$  /get.php?file=$1 [PT]
```

But it does not work.

Comment: The way you've put it, I think you need a regex that contains non-capturing look ahead/behind assertion... these can make your head spin!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tested this regexp in PHP <strike>it should work in mod_rewrite but I have not tested it</strike> and seems to work in mod_rewrite too:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)(?<!\.php)(?<!\.html)$ /get.php?file=$1
```

The rule will rewrite all URLs except those that end with *.php* or *.html*.

Comment: what about like http://myhost.tm/files/ or http://myhost.tm/files how to filter this as well?

Comment: It'll rewrite `myhost.tm/files` as `myhost.tm/get.php?file=files` but not rewrite `myhost.tm/files.php`. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Yes exactly.I move my get.php to separate directory so rewrite rule does not act  on it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way to handle that is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ get.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which will redirect everything, setting `file` to the value of the path.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work it brings infinity loop in the rule.

Comment: @Arman: It should not do, unless you fail to place the `[L]` bit on it, or use a redirect there after.

Comment: Yes, my failure, I moved the get.php in the separate folder and it starts to work. Thanks.